# amd radeon stuck on boot

Tags: 12.04, boot, ati, radeon

I recently tried installing Ubuntu, but it got stuck on the bootscreen with the purple dots. I pressed the <kbd>ESC</kbd> key for more info on where it hangs, and apparently it's with my graphics card (AMD Radeon HD 6670).
The 2 lines that I think is needed is these:

1. `fbcon: radeondrmfb (fb1) is primary device`
2. `fbcon: Remapping primary device, fb1, to tty 1-63`
   So I need to ask: how do I fix this :I

Comment: Please help ASAP :/